# Passing Object Array to Component VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to pass Object Array to my component but it's not passing the objects

Here is a sample data from the api

[image]

**home.vue**

```
<template>
   <PostRender :posts="posts"/>
</template>

<script>
import PostRender from "@/components/PostRender.vue";
export default {
    name: 'Home',
    components: {
        PostRender,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            posts: [],
        }
    },
    mounted() {
       this.getposts();
    },
    methods: {
       getPosts() {
                var token = this.$session.get('token');
                this.$http.get('api.domain.com/posts',
                {
                    headers: {
                        'Authorization':token
                    }
                })
                .then((response) => {
                    this.posts = response.data.posts;
                });
                
        }
    }
}
```

**PostRender.Vue**

```
<template>
   <div v-for="post in posts" :key="post.post_id">
      <div>{{post.title}}</div>
   </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'PostRender',
    props: {
       posts: { 
          type: Array,
          default() {
            return [];
          }
       }
    }
}
```

How can I pass the Object array from home.vue to postrender.vue?
Because it's returning null

Comment: Change `posts: { type: Object }` to `posts: { type: Array }`

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I tried your suggestion and  I have mounted a console.log to check if posts are being passed but it's returning null

`null PostRender.vue:144`

Comment: Well you define `posts: null` in your home components data, it should be initialized as `posts: []`. And change `:key="post.postid"` to `:key="post.post_id"`.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter I have ady updated the code it's returning an empty array Please refer to this picture :  https://prnt.sc/vjeesl

Comment: Have you verified your request to `api.domain.com/posts` is actually returning data? What do you see if you `console.log(this.posts)` immediately after `this.posts = response.data.posts;` ?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter in my getposts method: https://prnt.sc/vjeg66 the return response is https://prnt.sc/vjegr3

Comment: @DigitalDrifter More example:
Getposts method: https://prnt.sc/vjeh5i
return response: **before and after (this.posts)**  https://prnt.sc/vjehqo

Answer (score 1):

In **PostRender.vue** - posts property should be of type **Array**. I write it like this with default value:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: "Home",
  props: {
    posts: {
      type: Array,
      default() {
        return [];
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I have ady updated the code it's returning an empty array

Please refer to this picture : https://prnt.sc/vjeesl

Comment: For debugging purposes you can add a Watch with console.log in PostRender.vue to see if any data will come in the component. You can also do it with the Vue dev tool chrome extension. Do you see the data coming in the component?

watch: {
    posts: function(payload) {
      console.log("payload", payload);
    }
  }